# El modelo retorna un tipo de dato inválido en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy teneniendo un problema y es que cuando inicio sesión en mi página la vista me arroja el siguiente error. Soy nuevo en ASP.NET y no se a que se debe, asumo que el modelo esta enviando un dato de tipo NULL o 0 y no se hace la operación en la variable _conversionTotal.

El error que envía el explorador es el siguiente

[image]

Se define la variable totalActivaciones asi en el index.cshtml

```
 @{
                var totalActivaciones = Html.Action("IndicadorCuotaPorcentaje", "Analitica", new{_action = "CuotaActivacionesMovil",_fecha = false});
```

**Entiendo que el modelo responde la solicitud y el controlador actualiza la vista, pero me pierdo en el código ya que es un proyecto que desarrolló un tercero y soy nuevo en este lenguaje.**

La accion tiene la siguiente forma

```
public ActionResult IndicadorCuotaPorcentaje(string _action, bool _fecha )
            {
                string dato = "";
                IFact_tipo _activaciones = new Fact_tipo(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
                double _porcentaje;
                List<List<string>> listaValores = _activaciones.FACT_TIPO_INDICADOR_CUOTA(_action);
                foreach (var item in listaValores)
                {
                    //Si _fecha es TRUE entonces devuelve el valor de la fecha unicamente, sin porcentaje
                    if (!_fecha)
                    {
                        //Divide la cantidad acumulada entre la cuota
                        _porcentaje = Math.Round((float.Parse(item[0]) / float.Parse(item[1])) *100);
                        dato = _porcentaje.ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var dateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item[2]);
                        dato = dateAndTime.Day + "/" + dateAndTime.Month + "/" + dateAndTime.Year;
                    }
                }

                return Content(dato);
            }
```

*Edicion*

La variable `_conversionTotal` se declara en la vista de la siguiente manera

```
double _conversionTotal = Math.Round((float.Parse(totalAltas.ToString()) / float.Parse(totalActivaciones.ToString())) * 100, 2);
```

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de pegar una captura de pantalla con el código pégalo como texto para que sea mas sencillo de leer y de cortar/pegar si es necesario.De todas maneras, el error es claro, o `totalAltas` o `totalActivaciones` no es convertible en un float (es null? un espacio en blanco)???

Comment: Esto se refiere a que en la variable `TotalAltas` o en la variable `TotalActivaciones` son nulos, o el valor no corresponde a un valor numérico, y no se puede completar el método `float.Parse`, primero debes asegurarte que la variable sea diferente de nulo y su contenido sea un valor numérico.

Comment: @Flxtr @Pikoh precisamente eso es lo que no se como válidar, me pierdo en los archivos del controlador y del modelo al buscar la variable que se retorna. Se que el error es que el tipo de `totalAltas` o `totalActivaciones` es null o es Cero, sin embargo no se de donde viene esavariable, por eso pegue el capture de VS

Comment: Javier, veo que has realizado varias preguntas y no has aceptado ninguna de ellas, sugiero que si alguna de ellas te ha sido de ayuda y solucionado tus problemas le des clic en `✓`, esto ayuda a mantener la salud de las preguntas-respuestas así como ir incrementando una base de conocimientos sólida. Respecto a esta pregunta, de inicio cambia las imágenes por el código en texto, y luego prometo que tu problema se solucionará con mi ayuda :D

Comment: mas alla de cualquier cosa.. sabes que esas estructuras subrayadas con rojo son errores no? y si tu no sabes de donde vienen los nulos, nosotros menos sin tener todo el proyecto.

Comment: el codigo que pegaste, ademas, no se condice en nada con el error.. no esta ahi ese codigo..

Comment: @Javier el señor Bianchi tiene razón, ahora debes poner el código donde se declara la variable `_conversionTotal`, justo ahí es donde debemos poner algunas validaciones para evitar que se genere una excepción ;)

Comment: @Flxtr la pregunta fue editada, gracias por la colaboración ! @gbianchi si, entiendo que las estructuras subrayadas en rojo no son accesibles, sin embargo coloque el código ya que ahi esta definida la accion `IndicadorCuotaPorcentaje` o me equivoco??

Comment: @Javier pero el error que mostraste arriba no tiene nada que ver con eso!

Comment: Por favor, si puede revisa las preguntas que hiciste, acepta las respuestas que corresponden. y ven al [chat]

Comment: @gbianchi !! Encontre un back up de la base de datos, borre la que estaba y la restaure con el back up y funcionó, claro con datos del 2016 !! Eso quiere decir q no es el codigo fuente sino los procesos ETL !! Gracias por su ayuda amigos, cualquier duda o pregunta volvere por aqui !! Saludos !!